# Method to record golf strokes

Tags: java

The method is to record the number of strokes a player took when completing a hole. The method returns true when strokes are successfully recorded. There are 2 caveats: (1)the hole must be recorded in order and must start with 1. If a hole is received out of order, the score is not recorded and false is returned (2)The hole number must also be valid. You can't record a score for a hole that is less than 1 or greater than the number of holes on the course. When debugging my code give a java.lang.NullPointerException. What does that mean and how can i fix this.

Note: holesPlayed is an instance variable assigned the value of 0

Here is what i have:

```
public boolean recordStrokes(int holeNumber, int strokes) {
    if ((holeNumber >= 1) && 
        (holeNumber <= this.holesPlayed) && 
        (holeNumber == holesPlayed + 1 
    {
        scores[holeNumber -1] = strokes;    
        holesPlayed = holesPlayed + 1;    
        return true;
    }    
    else { 
        return false;  
    }
}
```

Comment: NullPointerException means (among other things) that you're trying to access the value of a variable you haven't initialized.

Comment: I changed some indentation in your code to make it more legible, but it looks like there is a syntax error on your condition for your if statement -- could you double check that you copied it correctly?

Comment: Also, if `holeNumber` MUST be 1 or greater, and `this.holesPlayed` is initialized to 0, won't it be impossible to get this method to return `true`? It seems to me like you need to remove your 2nd "if" condition.

Answer (score 0):

you've missed closing brackets for IF condition

```
 public boolean recordStrokes(int holeNumber, int strokes) {
        if ((holeNumber >= 1) && 
            (holeNumber <= this.holesPlayed) && 
            (holeNumber == holesPlayed + 1 )) <-- this brackets are missing in your code
        {
            scores[holeNumber -1] = strokes;    
            holesPlayed = holesPlayed + 1;    
            return true;
        }    
        else 
        { 
            return false;  
        }
    }
```

Comment: I agree that's a problem, but it would cause a compile-time syntax error, not a runtime NPE.  Seems like it's just a typo when copying the code to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure, but I'm going to make a guess that `scores` was never initialized. Do you initialize it somewhere with a line such as

```
scores = new int[NUM_HOLES];
```

?

Comment: Thanks, I have an instance variable: private int[] scores. I changed this: scores = new int[Course.NUM_OF_HOLES] to: this.scores = new int[Course.NUM_OF_HOLES]. I guess I was creating a new object instead of assigning a value to my instance variable

Comment: Did that fix your problem?